# mongo.exe Crash in windows 7 64x

Tags: mongodb, windows-7-x64

I download mongodb(windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ legacy)Binary from https://www.mongodb.org/downloads and exteract it to wamp/bin/mongodb and create data , data/db , conf , conf/mongodb.cong , logs , logs/mongodb.log file and folder and next run command like this code in windows cmd :

```
mongod.exe --install --config c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\conf\mongodb.conf --logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\logs\mongodb.log
```

but windows give me last error

[image]
      lkjii I try with mongo.msi but windows give me this error

Comment: Try to use MongoDB version 2.6.11. I have faced same problem and version 2.6.11  is working for me.